# Magento 2 admin session lifetime not extend the time more than 30 mintes

Tags: magento-2.1.7

I have put the session lifetime 84600 at admin side and cookies time same also. but after cleaning cache and again login, it does logout after 30 mints.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Since Magento 2.1 the admin session lifetime is always "session"

Comment: until the browser is closed. This has been might have been introduced for security reasons.

Comment: change session. gc_maxlifetime from 1440 to whatever number of seconds you desire. (This solution worked for me, tested on Magento 2.2.0 and 2.2.1)

Comment: where I have to put this code "session. gc_maxlifetime" on php.ini or htaccess file ?

Comment: okay wait adding an answer for the same

Comment: And also if I put this at php.ini or htaccess file an enable the flag session.auto_start = on than it does creating error at fronted. 
Error : "Fatal error: Magento\Framework\Message\Manager::addMessage(): The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition &quot;Magento\Framework\Message\Collection&quot; of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded _before_ unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition in ..././///"